# Dynamically set the text of a select element, by its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element, and two text boxes. When the user clicks a list option, the id and names (text) get populated in those two text boxes.

I want to be able to update the text portion of the select by the click of a button, making sure to update that of the id reflected in the text box. Here's what I've been working with:

HTML:

```
    <select name="categories" id="categories" multiple>
       <option value="1">Baby pictures</option>
       <option value="2">Animals</option>
       <option value="3">Nature</option>
    </select>


    <input type="text" name="catID" id="catID" />
    <input type="text" name="selCat" id="selCat" />
    <input type="button" id="update" value="update" />
```

jquery:

```
        $('#update').click(function() {
            var selID;
            var selCat;

            selID = $('#catID').val();
            selCat = $('#selCat').val();

            $('#categories').val(selID).text(selCat);
        })
```

I've tried several different things - this is the only one that actually has an effect on the list itself. Although, it completely empties it. heh

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: Unless `#categories` is a form field, `.val` won't work. What are you using the "id" stuff for? I don't understand what that value is to be used for

Comment: when the update button is clicked do you want to add a new option to the select element

Comment: about to post HTML. No, I don't want a new option to be added - I want the option of ID [x] to be updated to whatever is in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new option to the select element when click on the update button then try

```
$('#update').click(function () {
    var selID;
    var selCat;

    selID = $('#catID').val();
    selCat = $('#selCat').val();

    $('#categories').append($('<option />', {
        val: selID,
        text: selCat
    }));
})
```

---

To Update an existing item

```
$('#update').click(function () {
    var selID = $('#catID').val();
    var selCat = $('#selCat').val();

    $('#categories option[value="' + selID + '"]').text(selCat)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/37GZT/)

Comment: I'm not looking to add a new option to the list, but to update an option. After selecting an option, the user can change the name of that option - clicking update should set that option in the list to its new name.

Comment: @wribit You want to change the text of an existing option whose value is specified in the value cat txtfield

Comment: I want to update the option whose value = the id in the catID textbox, and set it's option "i.e. baby pictures" to whatever is in the selCat textbox.

Comment: Perfect! thank you Arun, you've answered my question. :)